# Generalized Inverse of Transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning, transpose, generalized-inverse

How can we show that **if** $G$ is generalized Inverse of $A$ ,

**then**  $G^T$ is  generalized Inverse of $A^T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have G defined by the properties

$$\begin{align}
& AGA = A\\
& GAG = G \\
\end{align}$$

Taking the transpose of both sides of each equation

$$\begin{align}
& (AGA)^T = A^TG^TA^T = A^T\\
& (GAG)^T = G^TA^TG^T = G^T \\
\end{align}$$

gets you the property you want.